# Why can't I log in to chat?

Tags: support, chat, user-accounts

This morning chat has decided my login credentials are too old and won't let me log in.

I've tried all the suggested things.

- Log out and log back in again.
- Clearing cookies.
- Trying four different browsers, one of which had never been to Stack Exchange before and has never had any extensions installed.

Is anyone else having such an issue and is there anything I didn't try?

Comment: I didn't experienced anything similar

Comment: I had it once before when I changed from Google Chrome dev channel to stable channel and blamed Chrome. This time I've changed nothing.

Comment: I have no problems too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I was originally having problems, the following link seemed to solve it for me:

[There is actually a specific chat login URL for each Stack Exchange site](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/chat-stackexchange-login).

Comment: A disguised URL is worse than a naked URL! It's like the Thai ladyboy of the URL world! d-;

Comment: mwaha, thought you'd like that one ;)

Comment: regardless, did it help?

Comment: Omg. This night was worse enough. I dreamed a lot of naked urls. But I fear that next night i'll be chased by ladyboys. I want my naked girls back!

Comment: Yes it did work. I didn't spot this thing in the page that's supposed to help with chat login problems. Where did you find out about it?

Comment: After hunting through pages of chat help when it wasn't working for me. Now it's a bookmark on my toolbar, so just copied from there ;)

Comment: @hippietrail this is covered at the bottom of the [Login help](http://chat.stackexchange.com/help) page, which is in turn advertised from the login page

Comment: Aha they gave every other trick a point but this one seems to be languishing in a comment without a point that came after my TL;DR cutoff (-: I'd post about it as a user interface issue on meta.SO but it would only get closed by the anal retentives there.